# Cors filter for localhost and staging url

Tags: java, spring, http, cross-domain, cors

We are developing a java-spring mvc project.
In order for the client team to be able to connect to our services we created a CorsFilter:

```
  @Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException,
    IOException {

// populating the header required for CORS

String responseURL = this.corsMap.get(request.getServerName().toString());
response.addHeader(
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
           (responseURL == null ? "https://default.ourCompany.com" : responseURL));

response.addHeader(
           "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
           "true");

if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
    // CORS "pre-flight" request
    response.addHeader(
               "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
               "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.addHeader(
               "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
               "X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type, Accept");
}

filterChain.doFilter(
             request,
             response);
}
```

Things to note:

1) we allow all for any OPTIONS incoming request.

2) We allow specific ip for "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" (since  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"=true requires so)

3) a map called corsMap contains all the client urls and their mapping to server urls, like so:

```
10.110.0.55->http://localhost
10.110.0.66->https://some.other.url
```

Now we have a problem:

We would like to use clients from "http://localhost"  AND from "http://some.other.url". how can we achieve that? (the problem here is that only a single client URL is allowed, and if the clients request can be received from multiple URL - we wont be able to determine what to allow).

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying that a single deployment instance of your server could be accessed from multiple clients simultaneously, right?

Comment: Yes,some of them will be accessed through a client build machine, while other will be accessed from developers PC (localhost)

Comment: None of the deployment would be accessed both by the client build machine and the developer's PC? If so, how about just having an application property which could be set in the deployment environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross domain requests, the request would be having an "Origin" header, which would later get matched with the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header (that we provide in the above filter).

So, I think, coding the `doFilterInternal` as below should work:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException,
    IOException {

    String clientURL = request.getHeader("Origin");
    response.addHeader(
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
           isInWhileList(clientURL) ? clientUrl : "https://default.ourCompany.com";
    ...
```

**Note**:

The latest version of Spring has [a new way](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) to configure CORS, which has an `allowedOrigins` method, which can take an array of whitelisted URLs.

You can also refer to [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon)'s source code for a concrete example.