# SimpleCORSFilter not working

Tags: ajax, spring

I am using Spring Rest as my backend, when I sent request by $.ajax{}, I got error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://121.40.249.129:8080/user/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

So, I added `SimpleCORSFilter` in my Spring Project:

SimpleCORSFilter:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

The since I don't have web.xml, so I didn't add the code to web.xml:

```html
<filter>
    <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>xxx.xxx.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So, I still get the error, how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As I have experienced, `*` won't work for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set to `true`.

So, you should instead have

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:8000");
```

Actually, instead of hardcoding the url, you can have that as a *property*. If you want to allow multiple origins, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035968/cors-filter-for-localhost-and-staging-url/32037743#32037743) would help.

Also:

1. It's advised to annotate the class with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`, because this filter should come first.
2. If you are using CSRF, the corrosponding header should also be added to the list in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

**Update**:

As *@RTzhong* did (see his comments below), replacing `*` with `request.getHeader("Origin")` seems like the ideal fix. However, a better security practice in general would be to specify the actual url or first [checking with a whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035968/cors-filter-for-localhost-and-staging-url/32037743#32037743), unless one must expose his API publicly to unknown websites.

Refer to [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon)'s source code for a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have changed my code to : response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("origin"));

Comment: Okay. Hope it's working now. Also, it is advised to annotate the class with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`, because it should come before any other filter.

Comment: Its not working with AuthenticationEntryPoint? For wrong credentials its not calling AuthenticationEntryPoint filter...Please help.. Thanks, Neha