# Spring Boot CORS configuration issue - Access-Control-Request-Method: POST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-web

I have a CORS config:

```
  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    LOGGER.info("Configuring CORS");
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:2199", "https://localhost:2199"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(
        Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin", "Cache-Control",
            "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Accept"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(
        Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
```

This works for this request:

`curl -v -XOPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3001' http://localhost:8080/auth/create-account`

It returns `200`

It does not work if I add `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST`

`curl -v -XOPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3001' http://localhost:8080/auth/create-account  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST'`

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthEndpoint {

@PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> doLogin(@RequestBody @Valid LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    LOGGER.debug("Attempting login {}", loginDTO);
    try {
    .....
```

Spring's log says:

```
2019-01-01 21:16:35.100 DEBUG 24848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : OPTIONS "/auth/create-account", parameters={}
2019-01-01 21:16:35.104 DEBUG 24848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> rest.AuthEndpoint.createAccount(NewAccountDTO)
2019-01-01 21:16:35.106 DEBUG 24848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-01 21:16:35.112 DEBUG 24848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-01 21:16:35.112 DEBUG 24848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2019-01-01 21:16:35.112 DEBUG 24848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Looks like the dispatcher servlet is intercepting it and killing it, but only with the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header, without that header it works.

Now, if I change the controller to add this: `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` both ways work.

My question is how do I globally configure my entire app to avoid having to decorate every REST controller with (what should be a redundant) `@CrossOrigin` annotation?

Comment: haven't you look at this - [Global CORS Configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors) ?

Comment: Add "OPTION" in setAllowedMethod arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue gave us a few headaches, but we managed to find a solution with Spring-Boot v2.3.3. The problem here is that an Options request with an `Origin` and `Access-control-request-method` header works fine as long as you:

1. Configure CORS in a `WebMvcConfigurer`.
2. Define `OPTIONS` in the `allowedMethods`.
3. Do NOT add any other CorsFilters.

For example

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
                                HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name())
                .maxAge(1000L); // in seconds
    }
}
```

However, we also used Swagger v2.9.2 and for some weird reason the WebMvcConfigurer above doesn't enable CORS for the Swagger `/v2/api-docs` endpoint. The solution for that, found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685909/741249), is to add a CorsFilter bean for example

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilterSwagger() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.setMaxAge(1000L);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

The problem is that as soon as we added this, the Options requests started to fail again. Ultimately, we upgraded Swagger to version 3.0.0 where the CORS issue for the endpoint is fixed, so after removing the CorsFilter everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Add "Options" in the allowed method

```
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization, User-Accept-Language");
    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with configuration, not a custom filter.

Answer (score -1):

Spring MVC global CORS configuration is described in [that blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#global-cors-configuration) I wrote and in the [Spring Framework reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors-global).

Spring Security will automatically detect Spring MVC CORS configuration and leverage it to authorize requests if you [enable CORS support at Spring Security level](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors).